{2005 Dodge Dakota 4.7L} If I only have two wheel ABS but got a 4 wheel ABS master cylinder, will the brakes still work?
Title pretty much says everything. It's a 2005 Dodge Dakota, 4.7L. I saw zero paint under the brake booster so went ahead and replaced that and the cylinder. I'm currently waiting on brake lines but just noticed the cylinder was for a 4-wheel ABS system, and mine only has a 2-wheel.
I do plan to get the right part, but once he gets the brake lines done, is it gonna drive home on the wrong part? It fit and everything perfect, and looks like the same part.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I believe most (if not all) ABS systems are setup so if the ABS fails (or doesn't work for some reason), the brakes will still work. Don't take my saying as gospel, though.
